# On the grammar tag // Über den grammar-Tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I have been observing people using the [grammar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) tag for all sorts of questions, many of which have absolutely nothing to do with grammar. [grammar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) is not the only very broad tag on the site, we also have:

- [meaning](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning)
- [usage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage)
- [sentence-structure](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sentence-structure)
- [spelling](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spelling)

All of which are outside of [grammar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar)’s scope. I have come across questions that *should* have had one of the tags above but were tagged [grammar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) instead.

**Please do not use [grammar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) if your question does not have anything to do with grammar!**

---

Ich habe schon häufiger Fragen gesehen, die mit dem Tag [grammar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) (Grammatik) getaggt wurden, deren Inhalt aber nichts auch nur im Ansatz mit Grammatik zu tun hat. [grammar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) ist nicht der einzige Tag mit einer breiten Verwendbarkeit auf dieser Seite; wir haben auch:

- [meaning](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning) (Bedeutung)
- [usage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage) (Verwendung)
- [sentence-struktur](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sentence-struktur) (Satzbau)
- [spelling](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spelling) (Rechtschreibung)

Alle diese decken Bereiche ab, die *nicht* von der Grammatik abgedeckt werden. Dennoch habe ich zu allen diesen Bereichen in letzter Zeit Beispiele gesehen, die fälschlicherweise mit [grammar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) getaggt wurde.

**Bitte den Tag [grammar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) nicht verwenden, wenn die Frage nichts mit Grammatik zu tun hat!**

Comment: Can you clarify why you consider sentence-structure as outside the scope of grammar? (AFAIK, grammar is more than morphology and includes syntax.)

Comment: People also often use grammar when they ask for a sentence being grammatically correct; although we have a tag specifically for that kind of question. That being said, I also feel that many people don't know how to tag their question and because tagging is required, they just look up what tags exist. Grammar happens to be the first one appear in the list because it's the one used the most. Hence, people tag their question with grammar. They are too lazy to search an appropriate one. This often comes along with sloppy questions. No effort taken into asking a good question, no effort for tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While we are at it: **Why do we not get rid of [grammar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) altogether?** The following arguments are adopted from [the analogous discussion on Meta Latin Language](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/56/49):

1. **There is no need for this tag.** Almost every question tagged *grammar* can be tagged with some more specific tag like *nouns, pronouns, grammatical-case, tenses, word-order* and so on. These are very helpful for searching, *grammar* isn’t. Admittedly, somebody could want to subscribe to or ignore the tag (some people actually do). However, I doubt that these people really get what they want, since they do not get all questions about grammar anyway, as many questions with a more specific grammar-related tag are not tagged grammar¹. Even despite this, they are describing to one sixth of the site’s questions.

   The only exceptions I can think of are questions where somebody encountered an unknown grammatical phenomenon and wants it identified or learn more about it. However, we can create a more specific tag for such questions, e.g., [grammar-identification](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar-identification) or [unknown-grammar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unknown-grammar).
2. **It keeps people from using useful tags** (even beyond what was described in this question). In my experience, many users tag questions about grammar with *grammar* and leave it at that. If they were not allowed to use the grammar tag, they are <s>forced</s> motivated to tag their question with more specific and thus useful tags from the beginning.

   Of course, we can and will try to retag all these questions, but my experience says that we will miss some of them, and this work can be somewhat alleviated. No guidelines on tag usage or tag warnings will prevent this, only blacklisting *grammar* will. As long as we have the *grammar* tag, we end up with a lot of poorly tagged grammar questions.

<sup>¹ And if they subscribed to all the other grammar-related tags, abolishing *grammar* would not matter to them.</sup>

---

Wenn wir schon mal dabei sind: **Lasst uns [grammatik](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammatik) komplett einstampfen.** Die folgenden Argumente sind weitgehend von der [analogen Diskussion auf Meta Latin Language](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/56/49) übernommen:

1. **Dieses Tag ist überflüssig.** Auf jede Frage mit diesem Tag kann auch zumindest ein spezifischeres Tag angewandt werden, zum Beispiel *Nomen, Pronomen, Fall, Tempus,* oder *Satzbau.* Solche Tags sind sinnvoll zum Suchen von Fragen; *Grammatik* nicht. Zugegebenermaßen kann jemand dieses Tag abonnieren oder ignorieren wollen (und einige tun dies auch tatsächlich), aber ich bezweifle, dass er damit glücklich wird, da viele Fragen, die mit einem spezifischeren Grammatik-Tag versehen sind, eben nicht mit *Grammatik* getaggt sind¹. Selbst dann abonniert so jemand ein Sechstel aller Fragen.

   Die einzige Ausnahme hiervon sind Fälle, in denen der Fragesteller es mit einem grammatischen Phänomen zu tun hat, das er nicht zuordnen kann. Aber für solche Fragen können wir ein spezifischeres Tag erschaffen, z. B. [grammatik-identifikation](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammatik-identifikation) .
2. **Es unterdrückt die Verwendung sinnvollerer Tags** (auch über das in dieser Frage beschriebene Problem hinaus). Meiner Erfahrung nach taggen die meisten Fragesteller Grammatikfragen mit *grammar* und belassen es dabei. Stünde ihnen dieses Tag nicht zur Verfügung, sind sie <s>gezwungen</s> dazu angehalten, von Anfang an ein spezifischeres Tag zu nutzen.

   Natürlich können und sollten wir versuchen, solche Fragen neuzutaggen, aber meiner Erfahrung nach werden wir nicht alle erwischen und es macht zumindest etwas Arbeit. Nichts was wir den Fragestellern an Hilfestellung geben wird dies verhindern, nur das komplette Sperren des Tags. Solange es existiert, werden wir mit schlecht getaggten Grammatikfragen leben müssen.

<sup>¹ Sollten sie diese Tags ebenfalls alle abonniert haben, sollte sie die Vernichtung des Grammatik-Tags nicht jucken.</sup>

Comment: Ein virtuelles +1 dafür, dass du auch in zwei Sprachen schreibst (die »Frage« war es ja nur, damit ich auch alle erwische, die Antwort betrifft ja eher nur die Regulären). Ein echtes +1 weil ich dem Vorschlag zu mindestens 75 % zustimme.

Answer (score 0):

The following arguments make me believe we should keep the [grammar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) tag:

- It will be hard if impossible to convince people that they should not tag their **question on grammar** with the [grammar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) tag.
- On asking people are **forced** to tag their questions. In case a highly specific tag for their issue does not yet exist they may not be able to easily find any tag that suits them and they may use a wrong tag instead. They may even create a new tag that may be too specific to be useful in the long run.
- Graduated language sites English Language and English Language Learnes repeatedly discussed removing this tag but until today decided to keep it to serve as an **additional tag for further specifiying** a topic. However there is an ongoing [Meta-discussion on ELL](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3332/consolidated-grammar-tag-discussions-and-a-clean-up-proposal) whether removal was possible at all.
- We can not easily replace this tag by a more meaningful tag or remove it alltogether on all those 1284 questions where it was used up today.
- There may be people wo subscribe or ignore it. Removing "their" tag may lead to irritations.
- More specific tags may be helpful for searching but are less likely to be subscribed to or to be ignored. It should be encouraged however to **add more specific tags** to the [grammar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) tag.
- Among our list of tags there are many other similarly wide tags which then would also have to be removed with the same arguments:
  [meaning](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning) [meaning-in-context](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning-in-context) [usage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage)  [word-usage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-usage) [nouns](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nouns) [verbs](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verbs) [words](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/words) [tools](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools) ...

---

Aus folgenden Gründen glaube ich, dass wir den [grammar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) Tag behalten sollten:

- Es wird nahezu unmöglich sein, die Leute davon zu überzeugen, dass sie ihre **Grammatikfragen** nicht mit dem Tag [grammar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) versehen dürfen.
- Wenn eine Frage gestellt wird, werden die Leute dazu **gezwungen** einen Tag zu benutzen. Wenn sie den hochspeziellen Tag für ihre Frage nicht finden können, besteht die Gefaht, dass sie einen falschen Tag wählen, oder einen hochspezifischen neuen Tag erstellen, der aber auf lange Sicht möglicherweise wenig hilfreich ist.
- Die graduierten Seiten English Language und English Language Learners diskutieren immer wieder, ob sie diesen Tag entfernen sollten. Bislang haben sie sich aber dafür entschieden ihn als Zusatztag zu anderen Tags zu behalten. Es gibt aber gerade eine [Diskussion auf ELL](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3332/consolidated-grammar-tag-discussions-and-a-clean-up-proposal) ob es überhaupt möglich ist, den Tag zu entfernen.
- Es ist keinesfalls einfach, bei allen 1284 Fragen [grammar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) durch einen besseren Tag zu ersetzen oder ihn ganz zu entfernen.
- Leute, die den Tag abonnieren oder ignorieren sind womöglich etwas irritiert, wenn er ersatzlos wegfiele.
- Spezifischere Tags machen Sinn, wenn es um die interne Suchfunktion geht, aber Abonnements oder Ignore-Listen werden schwieriger. Man sollte es vielmehr begrüßen, wenn zum [grammar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) ein weiterr, spezifischerer Tag hinzugefügt wird.
- Es gibt noch viele weitere, ähnlich breite Tags in unsere Tag-Liste, die dann strenggenommen ebenfalls entfernt werden müßten:
  [meaning](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning) [meaning-in-context](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning-in-context) [usage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage)  [word-usage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-usage) [nouns](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nouns) [verbs](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verbs) [words](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/words) [tools](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools) ...

Comment: Ich nummeriere Deine Punkte der Reihe nach: 1) Neue Nutzer können keine neuen Tags erstellen. Wenn sie den falschen Tag wählen, ändert sich im Wesentlichen nichts – wir müssen sowieso nachbessern. 2) Ja, es wird etwas Arbeit, aber ich denke, eine koordiniertes Retaggen (z. B. zwischen den Jahren) wäre sowieso mal eine gute Idee. 6) Ein paar dieser Tags würde ich ebenfalls einstampfen, beim Rest gibt es einen wichtigen Unterschied: [grammatik] ist niemals das einzige sinnvolle Tag einer Frage.